# Facebook shows aggregated open graph actions attachments based on the object and not on the action

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've created an action, and defined how the attachment should look like in "Configure Story Attachment".
It looks fine in the feed when there is only one post of this action type.
However, if there is more than one action, FB aggregates them into a list, which is fine, but it shows the **object's og:description** in the attachment of each action, and it seems to ignore the action's attachment configuration.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Is there any way I can control how attachment would appear when aggregated?